# Not able to create MS Access DB Connection with Java Code?

Tags: java, jdbc-odbc

I am able to create a connection with 64 bit office but I want to connect with 32 bit office.

Still after reading so many articles regarding this, I still am unable to create a DB connection with MS Access using Java

I have:

- 64 Bit JDK
- 64 Bit Windows
- 32 Bit Ms Office

Now I have created a DSN using **odbcad32** in SysWow folder because I have 32 bit MS Access.

Here is my Java code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb,*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Rahul/Documents/test.accdb;";
//Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:hello");

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("Select * from user");
while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
{
  System.out.println(rs.getString("fullname"));
}
```

Still getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

and if I change the Connection code above which is commented. I get this error :-

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I have installed AccessDatabaseEngine 32 bit, but still I am unable to create a connection.

If I try to create DSN using odbcad in System32 folder (for64 bit office), 
I get this error:

> the setup routines for the microsoft access dbase driver odbc driver could not be found

What am I missing here as I have tried everything.

Comment: Have you tried using 32-bit Java?

Comment: Yes. It is not working

Comment: What? This is something new. What is MacroHard?

Comment: So you mean i cannot connect to db in access  in 32 bit?

Comment: Yes i know that. I am not a noob. Access is a headache. MySQL is better

Comment: Did you try to use Windows like backslashes in your connection string? This should work with a 32-bit JVM. What are the error messages when using a 32-bit JVM? What Java version do you use?